# IOS: jump a position in a uitableview

Tags: ios, uitableview

in method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

usually you use an array to set

```
[cell.textLabel setTex:@"row"];
```

but if I want to jump a row?

at example at indexpath.row I don't want to have this cell in my tableview, is possible?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit?  Are you trying to remove a cell when tapped? Or change the text on a different cell when this one is tapped?

Comment: no no...for example if my text at position "10" of my array is a null string I don't want show cell at indexpath.row when it's 10, as a "continue" in a loop...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: Incorporate the tableView datasource method for row height.

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.row == NUMBER_TO_AVOID) {
        return 0.0f;
    }
    return 44.0f; //standard cell height
}
```

Comment: but I verify the condition in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Answer (score 1):

I have done this in several similar situations.  What you'll do is create a second array "activeItems". Or something like that. Iterate through your main data array and build the active array with the valid items. Than have your data source reference this array instead. This gives you an array that is accurately indexed to your table.

Comment: no it's a bad solution, I prefer Justin Amberson answer...thanks

Comment: Actually this is better. You should outsource your data method from the cellForRow... method and put your cell data into an alternate array. You are doing something computationally expensive if you are enumerating or looping while inside the cellForRow method. It'd be better to use a custom method to sort your data from "unsortedArray" into "sortedArray" and then just call for each piece of data from the sortedArray.  Upvoted

Answer (score 0):

You can put a condition in cellForRowAtIndexPath. Try this:

```
data = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

If (data != nil){
    [cell.textLabel setText:data];
}
else{
    // code that handles data if null
}
```

Comment: He has to keep in mind that you may not return nil in cellForRow, the tableView will expect a cell and if one is not returned there will be a crash.

Comment: Right you are there Justin. My apologies if I haven't pointed that out in my post. I was assuming that blackguadian already know that he has to return a value for cell.